# Как сравнить разные форматы дат?

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня в базе данных хранятся числа в строковом формате: "2019-02-23T21:27:18.461Z"

Мне нужно отсортировать получаемые даты из базы данных для их вывода клиенту.

Я создаю сегодняшнюю дату и завтрашнюю:

```
var today: Date = new Date;
    today.setHours(0); today.setMinutes(0);
    today.setSeconds(0); today.setMilliseconds(0);
    var tomorrow = today.getDate() + 1;
```

Но

```
y.deadLineDate > today && y.deadLineDate < tomorow
```

Не будет работать, так как я сравниваю разные типы данных.
Как их правильно сравнить?

Comment: сравниваешь где?

Comment: `var today: Date` в javascript данная запись приводит к ошибке синтаксиса. Если используется что-то дополнительное = стоит это указать

Comment: Привести к одному типу, очевидно 

Comment: Какого типа deadLineDate? Зачем что-то нужно сравнивать с «сегодня» для сортировки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `today` имеет тип `Date`.

Метод [`.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) возвращает число. Следовательно переменная `tomorrow` имеет тип `number`.

Далее идет попытка сравнить *какое-то* значение сначала с датой, а затем с  числом.

Если это значение `string`, тогда для случая даты следует воспользоваться [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) которая вернет строковое представление в нужном формате.

Со вторым сравнением сложнее: нужно было создать **новый** объект типа `Date` и уже к нему применить [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

---

Альтернативным решением может стать использование [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) Для нужного поля и дальнейшее сравнение именно с датами.

Comment: Отлично, привел к строковому формату) А что это дает, как сравнить строковые даты?
Есть вариант указанные вами с помощью Date.parse, но не слишком ли это мудренно?

Comment: @AdelKhalitov, _Отлично, привел к строковому формату)_ - так дальше у тебя все написано. тебе надо просто сравнить строки

Comment: Спасибо все работает, но очень много строк кода для такого маленького действия!

Comment: @AdelKhalitov, маленькое действие это какое? И вызов одной функции как-то не тянет на _много строк кода_.

Answer (score 1):

```
y.deadLineDate > today.toISOString() && y.deadLineDate < tomorow.toISOString()
```

Comment: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'string'.

Comment: @AdelKhalitov, javascript не может дать такую ошибку.

Comment: @Grundy Это typescript извиняюсь